# Conditional Logic and Looping

Tags: r

I am trying to create a conditional loop to create a new variable called BigSales which should be given a value of 'yes' if either the date occurred before 2012 or the total gross for the day exceeded $65 million.  Otherwise, it should be given a value of 'no'.

I tried:

```
  for(i in 1:45){
      if(movies$Gross[i] > 65 | movies$Date[i] < 2012-01-01){
        movies$BigSales[i] <- "yes"}
      else (
        movies$BigSales[i] <- "no"
      )
    }
```

But I got the error message:

```
Error in if (movies$Gross[i] > 65 | movies$Date[i] < 2012 - 1 - 1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

In addition to that, the data set contains 100 observations, but it is only reading 45. How can I solve this?

Comment: `2012 - 1 - 1` would be parsed and evaluated as 2010. Quote it and leave out the spaces if you want a date. And do learn to post a [MCVE]. It's only Complete if it has a data object.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add a conditional column in this matter, but there are tools out there that make this easier and more comprehensible.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
movies <- mutate(movies, BigSales = ifelse(Gross > 65 && Date < "2012-01-01","yes","no"))
```

You should also be careful working with dates - call `str(movies$Date)` to make sure it's of the "Date" type, and if not you should pass it to `as.Date`

To answer your question as you asked it, you didn't put quotes around the date you listed, so it tried to evaluate it as `2012 - 2`.  If you'd prefer to solve this problem with the code you have, use `"2012-01-01"`

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` is vectorised, meaning it takes each item from input vector, process for the condition and returns a vector.

Another point is that since OP has mentioned that date before `2012` will be considered as `BigSales` "yes". Hence checking for only `year` of `movies$Date` will do the trick.

In base R, solution could be in

```
movies$BigSales <- ifelse(movies$Gross > 65 | as.numeric(format(movies$Date,"%Y")) < 2012, 
"yes", "no")
```

Note : `movies$Date` is expected of type `Date` or `POSIXct`